# Making a chrome extension using youtube-dl shows error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-dl

I am developing a youtube video downloader extension for chrome using youtube-dl. The javascript works fine when run in browser, but does not work when loaded as an extension in broswer. Browser shows this error message. "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined".
I need your suggestions for it.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
var http = require('http');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.listen(4000, () => {
console.log('Server Works !!! At port 4000');
});

app.get('/downloadmp3', (req,res) => {
var url = req.query.url;
res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="audio.mp3"');
ytdl(url, {
    format: 'mp3',
    filter: 'audioonly'
}).pipe(res);
 });

app.get('/downloadmp4', (req,res) => {
var url = req.query.url;

res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="video.mp4"');
ytdl(url, {
    format: 'mp4',
    }).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: you don't use require in a browser, that's a nodejs concept - saying the javascript works in the browser makes no sense since .... a) `require('http')` - how's that going to work, since `http` is a built in module for nodejs and b) how will `require` work in the browser, since that's a nodejs thing - you must be doing something to that code before it just works in a browser

Comment: also, `.pipe` .. won't work in a browser - so I doubt this code works in the browser at all

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am actuallly learning javascript and chrome apps. The question is that either is it possible to make a chrome extension by changing the code from nodejs to the one that works in browser extension?

Comment: no, nodejs has direct access to the filesystem, a browser does not - still your question is saying that this works in the browser, when clearly it won't

Comment: This code works in browser and starts downloading videos. But the only problem is to convert it to make a chrome extension.

Comment: how do you make this code work in the browser? `require` won't work, `.pipe` wont' work, you can't have a *http server (express)* running in a web page ... no, this code you've posted does not run in the browser

Comment: This is the project link that I am following. https://github.com/Moorad/youtubeDownloader

Comment: yes, and the code you've posted in the question is the **server** code - server code rarely can be thought of as *running in the browser* - mainly because ... and this is a subtle point ... **it doesn't**

Comment: Thanks I got it. Now i need to find a way to use nodejs modules in chrome apps.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: built-in nodejs "modules" - like http, fs, etc - wont work in chrome apps - which are different than chrome web extensions anyway